# WinForms button click event not firing

Tags: c#, winforms, events, for-loop

I don't get any errors from Visual Studio so I assumed that the code was right. When I run the code, I press the button (`button1`), but nothing happens.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
    int a = 0;
    int b = 1;
    int c = 1;

    listBox1.Text += a.ToString();
    listBox1.Text += b.ToString();

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        c = b;
        b = a + b;
        a = c;

        listBox1.Text += b.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: A ListBox does not have a meaningful implementation for the Text property that it inherited from Control.  The reason that it is **hidden** in the Properties window.  It displays *multiple* strings, not just one.  Either use its Items.Add() method or use a Label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Listbox's [`Text`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.text(v=vs.110).aspx) property won't work in this case, since it is used only to set or get the selected item in a listbox, add to the itemsource on each number, then it will work

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int a = 0;
            int b = 1;
            int c = 1;
            StringBuilder finalstring = new StringBuilder();
            listBox1.Text += a.ToString();
            listBox1.Text += b.ToString();

            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                c = b;
                b = a + b;
                a = c;
                listBox1.Items.Add(b);
            }

        }
```

Comment: You don't need to call '.ToString()' when adding `b` to listbox items.

Answer (score 2):

Does `button` have `button1_Click` registered as an event?

You can do it via your code by adding `button1.Click += button1_Click`, or double clicking it in your form designer.

If this still does not work, put a [breakpoint](http://www.dotnetperls.com/debugging) on the code to see if it is executed.

Comment: I guess this is not the problem OP is facing!

Comment: I'll leave it hear for future searchers, +1 to you